# FM Actuary question, comparing interest rate and Discount rate

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, economics, word-problem, actuarial-science

On January 1, 2011, Tina invested P into a fund which accumulates at an interest rate of 3% compounded every 2 months. On January 1, 2012, Sam invested 50 in a fund with a discount rate of 6% compounded semiannually. On January 1,2011, the sum of the present value of the two funds is 100. Calculate the total combined amount that will be in the two funds on January 1, 2014.
A)106
B)108
C)110
D)112
E)114

So besides the actual arithmetic, the format of this question itself is not very straight forward for me. I'm not understanding how Sam can have money in his account in 2011 at all if he didn't deposit anything until 2012. Any ideas?

Comment: After researching "Discount Rate", I'm pretty sure what they mean by present value in 2011 is the amount of money that Sam would have had to invested in Jan 2011 to have the value in Jan 2012 be the 50 he actually did invest then. So pretend Sam invested $Q$ on Jan 2011 at 6% compounded twice a year. Figure out how much he would have in Jan 2012, set that equal to 50, and solve for Q. You also know that Q+P =100, so you can find P. Finally figure out what both accounts are worth in Jan 2014.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment, when computing the present value of a cash flow, you are not computing an actual balance in the sense of a realized amount of money.  Instead, you are computing the equivalent *time value of money* at a specified point in time.

To this end, we note that if $P$ is the present value of Tina's fund on 01 Jan 2011, and $Q$ is the present value of Sam's fund on that same date, then $P+Q = 100$.  Since the value of Sam's fund is $50$ on 01 Jan 2012, where the nominal semiannual discount rate is $d^{(2)} = 0.06$, then the effective annual rate of discount is $$d = 1- (1 - d^{(2)}/2)^2 = 0.0591.$$  This means that $$50(1-d) = Q,$$ or $Q = 47.045$.  Equivalently, we can observe that the effective annual interest rate is $$i = \frac{d}{1-d} = 0.0628122,$$ thus $Q(1+i) = 50$ and the answer is the same.  Consequently, $P = 100-Q = 52.955$, and the accumulated value on 01 Jan 2014 of both funds is $$P\left(1 + \tfrac{i^{(6)}}{6}\right)^{18} + Q(1+i)^3 = (52.955)(1.005)^{18} + (47.045)(1.0628122)^3 \\= 57.929 + 56.4785 = 114.4.$$  Note we could have obtained the accumulated value of Sam's fund by taking the value at initial deposit on 01 Jan 2012 and discounting it by two years; i.e., its accumulated value is also $50/(1-d)^2 = 50/(1-0.0591)^2 = 56.4785$.

Comment: Ok, I gave an upvote, but how do you know that you need to find the value of Sam's fund before 2012, as it states that he starts investing starting on January 1, 2012.